# Cannot write to file on Google App Engine Dev server with PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, development-environment, file-writing

I had this working literally just a few hours ago. Not sure what I did to mess it up, if anything. I am trying to use file_put_contents() to a test.txt file in my temp directory to test some stuff. I can't use print_r() or echo, because sometimes it is an ajax call I am testing. The errors I keep getting are:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(temp/test.txt): The local filesystem is readonly, open failed in sub-dirs.../request.php on line 62

Warning: file_put_contents(temp/test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in sub-dirs.../request.php on line 62
```

I am not on production. This is locally, and according to the docs, this should work:

> Storing data in the development web server
>
> Google App Engine for PHP supports reading and writing to Google Cloud Storage via PHP's streams API. A developer can read to and write from an object in Google cloud storage by specifying it as a URI to any PHP function that supports PHPs Streams implementation such as fopen(), fwrite() or get_file_contents().
>
> In the Development Server, when a Google Cloud Storage URI is specified we emulate this functionality by reading and writing to temporary files on the user's local filesystem. These files are preserved between requests, allowing you to test the functionality on your local development environment before deploying your code to App Engine.
>
> In the PHP development server streaming calls like fopen(), file_get_contents() on 'gs://' urls are mocked by reading and writing to the local filesystem.

I'm pretty frustrated, so any help is greatly appreciate. Will upvote.

Comment: FWIW "temp/test.txt" is not a Cloud Storage Path. In 1.9.18 we added support for in memory temp filesystem, so you could just do something like file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir() . '/test.txt', 'blah')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Staring SDK 1.9.18, dev_appserver disables local file writing by default to better simulate the production environment. You can enable file writing by adding "google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem=1" to your php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

While you're right, the development server should be able to simulate Google Cloud Storage, there is currently an issue (reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11690&thanks=11690&ts=1424427830), feel free to star it) about it.

If you're using the SDK version 1.9.18, just revert back to 1.9.17 and it should work (did for me at least)

Comment: Reported to be fixed on the version 1.9.19

Comment: Apparently it is a separate issue than that one, I opened an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=11729
You have to change your php.ini file.