# GoogleAppEngine wordpress complains (Could not create directory) on update and plugin install

Tags: google-app-engine, wordpress, google-app-engine-python

I have a problem updating wordpress or installing wordpress plugin in my local version of google app engine. I get the following message.

> Downloading install package from
>   https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/event-espresso-decaf.4.8.38.decaf.zip…
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Could not create directory.

With the same code base I am able install plugin using MAMP (Macintosh, Apache, MySQL, and PHP). However fails with google Pyton script (`dev_appserver.py`). 
I tried changing the permission of the file system by giving privilege to all user for write. Tried executing as `sudo dev_appserver.py .`. Followed the advice in other post, **No luck**.

Whats the problem here?, With MAMP all looks good in my local, but the same code break as I deploy to GAE (`​appcfg.py -A APP-ID update app.yaml`). Whats the problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cannot write to file on Google App Engine Dev server with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774537/cannot-write-to-file-on-google-app-engine-dev-server-with-php)

`Staring SDK 1.9.18, dev_appserver disables local file writing by default to better simulate the production environment. You can enable file writing by adding "google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem=1" to your php.ini file.`

I also wrote a blog post about running WordPress on App Engine flexible environment at:
https://wp.gaeflex.ninja/2016/03/25/using-wordpress-multisite/

Please give it a try too.

Comment: Thanks it resolved, but I have another one now. This seem to google-app-engine env issue as it works fine with MAMP.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418894/fatal-error-class-ee-dms-core-4-1-0-not-found-in-wordpressgoogleappengine